# Where is pageProps.session defined when using Next-Auth?

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

From the provided snippet

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"
export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

What is the prop `session` and where is it set?

Comment: It's given by next-auth and it's the current session (probably null or undefined if the user is not logged in).

Comment: Where is that prop injected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is somewhat counter-intuitive. If a page component has a `getServerSideProps` function exported, it is expected that these properties be passed as props to the page component. For example:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: { foo:'Hello!' },
  }
}

export default function PageComponent(props) {
  return <div>{ props.foo /* = "Hello!" */ }</div>;
}
```

The counter-intuitive part is that this `props` is passed to the `_app.tsx` (or `_app.jsx`) component as `pageProps`.

In other words, the `getServerSideProps` should look like this:

```
import { unstable_getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import { authOptions } from "../api/auth/[...nextauth]"

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
   const session = await unstable_getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)

   return {
      props: {
         session
      }
   };
}
```